# Is there a way to change default extension for an empty text file in PCManFM

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, pcmanfm

I am using PCManFM 1.2.5 on XUbuntu 18.04 LTS. Currently when creating a new text file i get a creation window in the following form:

[image]

I would like to change the default extension from `txt` to `text`, since i believe that the whole 8.3 is a legacy that should be avoided where possible.

Comment: Could you please expand on "since i believe that the whole 8.3 is a legacy that should be avoided where possible."

Comment: Instead of creating a new text file, why not choose the *Empty File* option? You can name it anything you like.

Comment: @DKBose Because my intention is to change the default extension, not to type the same extension again and again. And i don't know what to expand. I believe that 8.3 is an archaic format for file names.

Comment: "For example, the older MS-DOS FAT file system supports a maximum of 8 characters for the base file name and 3 characters for the extension, for a total of 12 characters including the dot separator. This is commonly known as an 8.3 file name." From [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) and it's quite irrelevant now. You don't even have to use an extension for plain text files. I do because I like to do so.